# Кнопка с выпадающим списком

Tags: c#, wpf, dropdown

Нужно реализовать кнопку следующего вида 
[image: Кнопка с выпадающим списком]

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю на основе чего её сделать, так что бы выпадающая часть была шире самой кнопки и имела данное расположение. Не нужно писать код за меня, просто в 2ух словах скажите на основе какого элемента сделать и что менять

Comment: Да много из чего можно можно сделать такое. ToolTip, Menu, ComboBox, Expander. Выбирайте под свою задачу и вперед!

Comment: (Toggle)Button + Popup/Menu для велосипедов или WPFToolkit из готового

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, можно стилизовать контекстное меню:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyContextMenuStyle" TargetType="ContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="-18"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Path Data="M10,10 L18,0 L26,10" Fill="LightGray" Stroke="Black"/>

                        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="0,3">
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Кнопка" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Style="{DynamicResource MyContextMenuStyle}">
                <MenuItem Header="Элемент 1"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Элемент 2"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Элемент 3"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Элемент 4"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]