# WPF Popup arrow

Tags: c#, wpf

Можете помочь реализовать такой popup со стрелкой сверху? Заранее спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за черный квадрат и где попап?

Comment: Примерно как здесь, только у вас Popup будет, а не ContextMenu: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/954047/218063

Comment: Это точно не `ToolTip`? По идее, можно тултип обвешать стилями, получится то же самое, всплывающее при наведении мыши на что-нибудь.